# How to get Wordpress menus into Astro

Tags: astrojs

I'm paying about with a headless Wordpress / Astro setup. I've been following a few different guides but they all seem out of date now. Looks like Astro had quite some development over the last 6-12 months.

I'm really struggling with getting the primary menu to function. I can get the menu to list my pages/pages but none of the links go anywhere, and there is no hierarchy parent and child items are displayed all as one.

This is what I have in my src/lib/api.js

```
async function fetchAPI(query, { variables } = {}) {
    const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    const res = await fetch(API_BASE_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
    });
  
    const json = await res.json();
    if (json.errors) {
      console.log(json.errors);
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch API');
    }
  
    return json.data;
  }        

export async function getPrimaryMenu() {
        const data = await fetchAPI(`
        {
            menus {
              nodes {
                menuItems {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      path
                      label
                      connectedNode {
                        node {
                          ... on Page {
                            isPostsPage
                            slug
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `);
        return data?.menus?.nodes[0];
      }
```

Then my Header.astro contains:

```
   ---
import { getPrimaryMenu } from '../lib/api';

const { menuItems } = await getPrimaryMenu();
---

<header class="bg-slate-400 py-5 px-10 text-center">
    
    <nav class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between p-6">
        <a class="text-lg font-bold inline-block bg-slate-700 text-white py-4 px-8 rounded-md" href="/">Astro + WP</a>
        <ul class="flex items-center justify-end flex-grow">
          {menuItems.edges.map((item) => 
              <li key={item.node.path}>
                  <a href={item.node.connectedNode.node.slug} class={`cursor-pointer p-4 ml-2 text-white`}>
                      {item.node.label}
                  </a>
              </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </nav>
</header>
```

Curious to know where I'm going wrong, and what the fix is.

Comment: you'll need to provide a lot more info so that anybody can help you, for starters, what does `fetchAPI` refer to. but honestly, I never understood why anybody would use wordpress as a headless cms... there are much better ones out there for that case...